# Magento 2 remove image slider preview from product detail page

Tags: magento2.2, product-view

I want to remove "slider preview(gallary images)" from product detail page.

Answer (score 1):

To remove "slider preview(gallery images)" we have to change the code in our theme `view.xml` file.

file location :

> app/design/frontend/your_themepackage/your theme/etc/view.xml

```
<var name="nav">false</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
```

Comment: you answered your question so soon. Great.